# Azure DevOps Pipeline - Commits since last run

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, teamcity

My Team are migrating from TeamCity to Azure DevOps for CI, one thing that has been really useful in Teamcity is the build shows a "XX Pending" which lists all the commits to the specified branch  made since the build was last run, see below.
[image]

Is there an equivalent feature in DevOps **YAML** Pipelines - the important point here is it is used **before** a build is run, so the team can be confident what they are going to run has the right code in it. I was considering an initial build stage with a manual approval on the repo, but that feels onerous as they have to run the pipeline first, is there  something more elegant built in, or a better solution, or is this the only option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such equivalent. And I don't think this functionality will be easy to provide as an extension either.

I must say that in 15 years using Azure DevOps/Team Foundation Server I've never missed this feature... But I can see its use.

Comment: Thanks @jessehouwing, I can understand that if you have never had it then you don't miss it, but every time I introduce one of my team to DevOps it's the very first question they ask at the end of the demo, and the disappointment is palpable when I tell them it doesn't have it. Would be a good feature request and would make the transition a lot smoother, people don't like change, and for better or worse this is a crutch they have come to depend on

Answer (score 0):

> I was considering an initial build stage with a manual approval on the repo, but that feels onerous as they have to run the pipeline first, is there something more elegant built in, or a better solution, or is this the only option?

Compared to the way TeamCity just shows you the commits right there, there certainly isn't anything more elegant built in to AzDO. However, there are quite a few ways to see those commits, which may be arguably "more elegant" than kicking off a new pipeline to learn that information.

If you click on the most recent AzDO pipeline run, at the top you will see the branch name (e.g. `main`) and the commit ID it ran against (e.g. `1a2b3c4d`). TeamCity shows you the equivalent of the following commands, which you can run from any local client that has the AzDO repo as the remote (assuming it's called `origin` here):

```
git fetch
git log 1a2b3c4d..origin/main --oneline
# Suggestions to modify the log command:
# remove --oneline to see the full commit message, and/or
# add --graph to see the shape of those commits
```

Note in the pipeline view, the branch `main` and commit ID `1a2b3c4d` are also links. You can select the commit ID and copy it, then click on `main` to see it's contents and on the history tab you'll see the commit history graph. Just search for the commit ID you copied (e.g. `1a2b3c4d`) and you can visually see the commits that are merged in above it, which will be included in the next run against `main`. (This is probably even easier in a local UI tool, especially if the last run is behind by more commits than can fit on the first screen of the history view.)

Having used both AzDO Pipelines and TeamCity to run manual builds, I confess that most of the time I've already viewed the commits locally and already *know* I wish to start a Pipeline, rather than the other way around. That being said, in TeamCity, even if I already know I want to fire one off, I still find myself hovering over the pending commits, just because it's there and I like the extra confirmation, so I definitely see how you could miss that feature if you are used to it.

This might be a nice feature request for AzDO Pipelines.